# Redirection only if the button is clicked on the previous page

Tags: javascript, dom-events

I'm trying to achieve redirection only if the button is clicked on the previous page. I'm new to JS, so please be gentle.

For example:
When the users come on login page they have this button:

```
<button type="submit" class="form-login-submit" name="login" value="Log in">Log in</button>
```

When you click on Log in button you will be redirected to the My Account page which contains this class `member-logged-in` in `body`.

So, this is my code:

```
const logInBtn = document.querySelector('.form-login-submit');

logInBtn.addEventListener('click', () => {
  window.onload = () => document.body.classList.contains('member-logged-in') ? window.location.href = 'www.test.com' : '';
});
```

But when the user is redirected to the My Account page I'm getting this error, I think because the Log in button is missing on that page:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'addEventListener' of null
> at (index):691

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: What is the goal behind that ? Why would you want to redirect people, if they clicked on a button ?

Comment: The goal is to be redirected and to skip the My Account page as soon as they log in. But only after they log in (after clicked the button). If they later get back to the My account page nothing should be happening.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can solve this using `localStorage`. Maybe it's dirty solution but it will work.

```
const logInBtn = document.querySelector('.form-login-submit');
const isPage = window.document.href = 'https://test.com/my-account/';

logInBtn ? logInBtn.addEventListener('click', () => localStorage.setItem('justLogin', 1)) : 0;

if (isPage == 'https://test.com/my-account/' && localStorage.getItem('justLogin') && document.body.classList.contains('member-logged-in')) {
    localStorage.removeItem('justLogin');
    window.location.href = 'https://test.com/members/';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just keep the `window.onload = () => document.body.classList.contains('member-logged-in') ? window.location.href = 'www.test.com' : '';` part of the code.

This, assuming you already have some functionality in place which adds that class to the body element if the button was clicked.

Comment: But in this way, users will be redirected every time when they visit the My Account page. The goals are to be redirected only once after they log in ( after they click on Log in button )

Comment: @Marko, the login action is actually done on the server. It would be much easier to just let the server send an HTTP Redirect response header. Clicking on the Login button doesn't guarantee the user actually inserted his credentials nor that those credentials were correct.

Answer (score 0):

```html
const logInBtn = document.querySelector('.form-login-submit');

logInBtn.addEventListener('click', () => {
  //window.onload = () => document.body.classList.contains('member-logged-in') ? window.location.href = 'www.test.com' : '';
});

window.onload = () => {
    var logInBtn = document.querySelector('.form-login-submit');
    logInBtn.addEventListener('click', () => {
        var el = document.querySelector('.any-element');
        if(el.classList.contains('member-logged-in')){
            window.location.href = 'www.test.com?click=true';
            / Now it's clear on the server that there was a click from the previous page
        } 
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are using Vanilla Javascript in your project and the same script is loaded on your accounts page.
Add an if check for your addEventListener and you are done.

```
const logInBtn = document.querySelector('.form-login-submit');

if(logInBtn) {
  logInBtn.addEventListener('click', () => {
    window.onload = () => document.body.classList.contains('member-logged-in') ? window.location.href = 'www.test.com' : '';
  });
}
```

Comment: Good and simple logic, but for some reason, this doesn't work. Have no errors in the console as well.